# size reduction of matrix whose rank is not full in julia

Tags: algorithm, matrix, julia

I have a N×N general matrix **H** with rank n(<N).
Is there any way to get a n×n matrix with rank n from **H**?

For example,

```
      |1     2     3|
  H = |4     8     6|
      |0     0     1|
```

has three eigenvalues **0,1,9** and its rank is **2**. I want to get **a 2×2 matrix with rank 2** which corresponds to the eigenspace sappaned by eigenvectors of **1,9**.

Comment: Is this a Julia question or a linear algebra question? Do you already know of an algorithm, and need help to implement it in Julia? If not, maybe math.stackexchange.com is a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: The eigenvectors have three elements, though. Maybe you want the (compact) singular value decomposition?

Comment: In what basis do you want this matrix?  In the basis of the eigenvectors it will be `[ [1 0] [0 9] ]`.

Answer (score 1):

We are given a 3x3 matrix `H` that is known to have rank `r < 3`:

```
1 2 3
4 8 6
0 0 1
```

One can obtain an `nxn` matrix comprised of the intersection of rows and columns of `H` that has rank `n` by computing the [reduced row echelon form (RREF)](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/matrixtransform.html) of `H` (also called the *row canonical form*).

After doing so, for each of `n` row indices `i` there will be a column in the RREF that contains a `1` in row `i` (i.e., the row having index `i`) and zeroes in all other rows. It is seen [here](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/cgi-bin/matrix_canon_form.cgi) that the RREF of `H` is the following.

```
1 2 0
0 0 1
0 0 0
```

As column `0` (i.e., the column having index `0`) in the RREF has a `1` in row `0` and zeroes in all other rows, and column `2` has a `1` in row `1` and zeroes in all other rows, and no other column has a `1` in one row and zeroes in all other rows, we conclude that:

- `H` has rank `2`; and
- the `nxn` matrix comprised of elements in `H` that are in rows `0` and `1` and columns `0` and `2` has rank `n`.

Here an `nxn` matrix with rank `n` is therefore found to be

```
1 3
4 6
```

The same procedure is followed regardless of the size of `H` (which need not be square) and the rank of `H` need not be known in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [RowEchelon.jl](https://github.com/blegat/RowEchelon.jl) package, we can apply the method described in @CarySwoveland's answer pretty easily. (This is not my area of expertise though, so any corrections to it are welcome; specifically, the choice of rows as 1 to number of pivots is an educated guess based on some trials.)

```
julia> H = [1 2 3 
            4 8 6
            0 0 1];

julia> using RowEchelon

julia> _, pivotcols = rref_with_pivots(H)
([1.0 2.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0], [1, 3])

julia> result = H[1:length(pivotcols), pivotcols]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  3
 4  6
```

The package is just a home for code that used to be in Base Julia, so you can even just [copy the code](https://github.com/blegat/RowEchelon.jl/blob/master/src/RowEchelon_with_pivots.jl) if you don't want to add it as a dependency.